# Is it possible to use axios post request inside another axios response?

Tags: javascript, axios

Is it possible to do something like this or is it another method to do that?

```
axios.post("/url/url", data)
    .then(response => {
        //some functions with data from response to make newData;
        axios.post("/someurl/", newData)
            .then(response => {
                //some functions         
            })            
});
```